# Change timezone without administrative privileges

Tags: security, permission

We have some new compliance restrictions which require us to remove administrative access from users who do not require it in their day-to-day job.

Sometimes one of our QA's is required to change their timezone to test something in our product. They do not need any other administrative level access to complete their role.

The problem is that to change the timezone, a user needs to enter a password with sudo permissions.

How can we enable the user to change their timezone without administrative permissions?

PS. Appologies if any of my terminology is incorrect. We primarily support Windows users where we can achieve this using various policy configurations.

Comment: You fix (sorry, but it's broken, it really is) the default `sudo` configuration so that such a user can only use the commands you want them to use, rather than giving them unrestricted admin access.

Comment: @MarcWilson can you expand on what you mean? I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: You don't want to give them admin rights.  Fine.  But macOS adopts the same broken `sudo` configuration most Linux distributions do, where admin is god.  Create another group, give them rights to do only what you want, say just run `date`, and you're done.